# How to use absolute path for package references?

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

I use some open source libraries (rewrites version) for dotnet core 5.
In my solution we must use some another libraries which isn't open source and they have dependency on some of they open source libraries. At run time we get this error:
`System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'One.OpenSource.Package, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)`

How you can fix this?

Comment: @nilsK That's for .NET Framework, not .NET Core

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to set the path where DLLs are loaded from in .NET Core. Is it such a big deal to copy them to your output folder?

Comment: @DavidG okay, i removed the dupilcate vote. The question was tagged .net and .net-core. .net tags description states: "Do NOT use for questions about .NET Core". But hey, I did not read the first line in this post carefully, so ... ;)

Comment: It might not be supported in .Net Core 5.